# Q: How Robycopy deals with pointers to directories (short-cuts)

Tags: batch, robocopy, ms-dos

For example, in the statement below

```
robocopy %src%  %target% copy:DATSO
```

the parameter `%src%` may be a pointer to a directory.
In my case, Robocopy FAILED TO COPY the content the pointer is pointing to.

In case above `%src%` is a shortcut to directory created in Windows (8.1) Explorer by “dragging” directory icon (the icon picture & properties verify that it is Wndows “short cut”)

I’m aware that the parameter `/SL` forces Robo to copy the pointer-icon only

Comment: Shortcuts are not file system level pointers. They are a windows File Explorer / UI way to reference another directory using a special file called a link file (.lnk). Use a symbolic link to have a pointer to a directory at the file system level.

Comment: @Brian Many thanks for the clarification. Kind of guessed that i'm climbing the wrong tree.. But hey, by "guessing" one gets nowhere